# Rails, given an AWS S3 URL, how to use a controller to send_data / file to the requestor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given an Amazon S3 URL, or any URL that is a direct URL to a file. In my controller, given this URL, I want to send the user the file, whatever it is w/o redirecting.

Is this possible?

Comment: If your aim is to store files securely (private) on S3 and stream them only to authorized users, look at this: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think that's possible from your end. That's why many sites say "right click to save" or something along those lines. Some sites even have links to videos that say "click to download" but when I click the link they start streaming. These are due to MY settings (ie. the settings on the user's client). You can't control that.

If what you're trying to do is HIDE the location of a file...

> Send files back to the user - Usually,
>   static files can be retrieved by using
>   the direct URL and circumventing your
>   Rails application. In some situations,
>   however, it can be useful to hide the
>   true location of files, particularly
>   if you're sending something of value
>   (e-books, for example). It may be
>   essential to only send files to logged
>   in users too. send_file makes it
>   possible. It sends files in 4096 byte
>   chunks, so even large files can be
>   sent without slowing the system down.

From an [old blog post](http://www.rubyinside.com/19-rails-tricks-most-rails-coders-dont-know-131.html)

Comment: Thanks, it's actually a little more complicated. I want to use the Google Doc Viewer, but when you send the google doc viewer a private AWS3 URL with the two secret key params, it breaks the google doc viewer. So My idea was to send the Google Doc Viewer to a clean url on my end, and send it the file there.

Comment: i was able to get it to work with something like this: send_data open(@temp_url.aws_url) {|f| f.read }, :filename => @temp_url.file_name  problem is while it is sending the file, it still doesn't work. Perhaps it's a meme type issue

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with this info and see if you get some better answers. Good luck!